# SwiftUI is there any way of getting a disabled TextField to be grayed out on Mac OS

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

When a SwitfUI TextField is disabled, on Mac OS, there is no visual feedback that the field is not enterable (apart from not accepting focus click).  I have searched high and low, it **looks** like simply setting .background(Color.whatever) works for IOS (from all the "how tos" that I have encountered).  However for a Mac OS app, it only changes the color of the thin boundary of the textfield.  I have futzed around and found that I can add opaque overlays to simulate the effect, but that seems overly complex for what I always took to be conventional standard of greying out of disabled fields.  Which makes me think that I am missing something bleedingly obvious somewhere.

Has anyone a sample of a MacOS SwiftUI struct that greys the background of a disabled TextField ?  My minimal example of what I am doing to see the issue is below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var nameEditDisabled = true
  @State var myText = "Fred"
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("Change Name") {
        nameEditDisabled.toggle()
      }
      TextField("hello", text: $myText)
        .background(nameEditDisabled ? Color.gray: Color.yellow)
        .disabled(nameEditDisabled)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered that, if the *normal* behaviour on MacOS is for there to be no visual feedback, your application will be considered wrong or odd by acting differently?

Comment: I take your point. Looking through the Mac Preferences, the "convention" appears to be that a disabled field has grey text and an enabled field black.

Comment: Nonetheless, for me as a novice, the difference in apparent functionality of the same base code between IOS and MacOS  is worthy of note (even given that what I was trying to do would be considered poor practice ;-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to be "fixed' in swiftUI 3.0, macos 12. I get a slightly darker shade of gray when disabled. When in focus, I get a blue border.

Edit:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var nameEditDisabled = false
    @State var myText = "Fred"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change disabling") {
                nameEditDisabled.toggle()
            }
            TextField("hello", text: $myText)
                .colorMultiply(nameEditDisabled ? .gray: .yellow)
                .disabled(nameEditDisabled)
        }.frame(width: 444, height: 444)
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted by Damien I was trying for a non-convention.  To follow convention, I would replace the background line with  .foregroundColor(nameEditDisabled ? Color.gray: Color.black)

Comment: I've edited the answer with a "non-conventional" way. This gives you a yellow background when enabled, and a "conventional" gray background when disabled.

Comment: Many thanks, it does just what I was trying to achieve.  "colorMultiply".... would never have got to that.  You learn something new every day :-)

Comment: glad it helped. If you could tick the answer as correct, that would be good as well.

Comment: A side note: Use .white to keep the original color, and use Color(uiColor: .systemGray6) for a slight gray out.